# Filter elements of an array of objects comparing by various properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have a Javascript function that removes the elements of an array of objects that have the same property. What I am trying to do is create a generic method that can filter by several properties, and if there are two equal objects, filter by the property that has the highest value (`test3`)

This is the function I currently have, what I'm trying to do is make the `function as generic` as possible. What I want is for the `keyConditional` variable to be optional, but in this case, if I don't pass that variable to it, the function doesn't return anything. How can I solve this so that it is not mandatory to pass the `keyConditional`? How can I make this function as generic as possible to filter any object by any key (one or more)?

```js
 let dataObj = [
  {
    "test1": "model",
    "test2": "dataFile",
    "test3": "2022-06-15"
  },
  {
    "test1": "model",
    "test2": "dataFile",
    "test3": "2022-06-10"
  },
  {
    "test1": "data",
    "test2": "mode",
    "test3": "2022-06-08"
  }
]

function filterObjectsSomeKeys(dataObj, keysFilter, keyConditional) {

  const result = Object.values(dataObj.reduce((prevValue, currValue) => {
    const key = keysFilter.map(key => 
      currValue[key]
    ).join('|');

    if (keyConditional) {
      if(!prevValue[key] || prevValue[key].keyConditional < currValue.keyConditional) {
        prevValue[key] = currValue;
      }
    }
    return prevValue;    
  }, {}));

  return result;
}

console.log(filterObjectsSomeKeys(dataObj,['test1','test2'],'test3'))
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove objects that are exact duplicates? Or objects that have some property in common? Your question makes it sounds like the former, but you have no objects that are exact duplicates in your example. The description states that the first two objects are the same, but they have different dates.

Comment: @Josh I have changed the title of the question. What I am trying to do is remove the objects that have the same defined properties, and leave the object where the `test3` is greater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate the array directly without getting values from the object, which ist an additional superfluous step.

For using more than one key, take an array of keys and build a combined hash value and take only the object if the hash does not exist or the wanted key of the actual object is greater than the latest value of the same key.

```js
const
    filter = (array, group, keyConditional) => Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
        const key = group.map(k => o[k]).join('|');
        if (!r[key] || keyConditional && o[keyConditional] > r[key][keyConditional]) r[key] = o;
        return r;
    }, {})),
    data = [
        { test1: "model", test2: "dataFile", test3: "2022-06-15" },
        { test1: "model", test2: "dataFile", test3: "2022-06-17" },
        { test1: "data", test2: "mode", test3: "2022-06-08" },
        { test1: "data", test2: "raw", test3: "2022-01-01" }
    ];

console.log(filter(data, ['test1', 'test2']));
console.log(filter(data, ['test1', 'test2'], 'test3'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Ok ok, I was trying with the Object.keys() method but I didn't get the same result, I'll try this way. But how can I get the object with the most recent date? I need the object `{ test1: "model", test2: "dataFile", test3: "2022-06-15" }` instead of the object `{ test1: "model", test2: "dataFile", test3: "2022-06- 10" }`

Comment: I have updated the question, I am adapting your method to a generic function but I still have some problem

Comment: @segmet, please see edit.

Comment: I understand what you are doing now by passing the keys directly to it, that is what I have added in my function, the problem is that I don't know how to make the keyConditional optional, that it doesn't take it into account if it is not informed. Can you edit on the function that I have put?, to be able to improve it as much as possible

Comment: what object do you want to have it instead, the first of the same keys or the last found?

Comment: In case the `keyConditional` is not informed, the first object is kept

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, this should work.

```js
const result = dataObj.reduce((mostRecentObject, currentObject) => {
  const mostRecentObjectTime = Date(mostRecentObject['test3'].getTime()
  const currentObjectTime = Date(currentObject['test3'].getTime()

  const currentObjectIsMoreRecent = currentObjectTime > mostRecentObjectTime

  return currenctObjectIsMoreRecent ? currentObject : mostRecentObject
}, dataObj[0])
```

This should return the object within the `dataObj` array where the value of `test3` is the most recent.